# Configuring of Network Based Intrusion Prevention System from Open Source

Tags: windows-xp

We have get task for Final Project "Configuring of Network Based Intrusion Prevention System from Open Source" during my final semister.

```
  We have no knoledge about this. Please tell about Snort_Inline and which platform is best for install it & How can configure it.
```

Comment: I thought "send me codez"-style questions remained in the past :-)

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an IPS is usually done on a Unix/Linux OS. I would recommend sticking to Linux, as it doesn't seem to be a common thing to install as snort_inline on windows. I'm sure it's possible, but the better docs seem to be on Linux installs. Just get a virtualbox installation of ubuntu and fool around with that